# INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot parse ProtoValue kind Unknown as STRING;

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-automl

Hi I'm trying to use the nodejs of @google-cloud/automl, if follow the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/predict?authuser=1#automl-tables-example-nodejs)
but I received the error *"INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot parse ProtoValue kind Unknown as STRING; Error parsing STRING value; Error parsing ProtoValue for column"*.
And my code I pass string every time.
The same code writes in python work.
I've no idea to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Not sure if this was your problem, but it was mine.

In my opinion, the tutorial was unclear on what to pass as input. I thought 'numberValue' and 'stringValue' were just foobar keys meant to be replaced with the column headers of my own table. Turns out they aren't foobar. For every variable you want to pass, you need to classify its type. You do not need to pass your header names. For example input might look like:

```
const inputs = [
 { stringValue: "abcd" },
 { stringValue: "1223" },
 { numberValue: 200 }
 { stringValue: "2021-03-26" }
];
```